# NestJS - Axios Oath2 get third party access token

Tags: oauth-2.0, nestjs, typeorm

I am newby on NestJS I wrote following code to get access token from third party but API respond `data: error: 'invalid_request', error_description: 'Missing Mandatory Parameters'}`  may be I am missing headers or something else.

Following code I am using:

```js
async getEquifaxToken() {
    const token_params = {
        grant_type: 'client_credentials',
        client_id: 0000,
        client_secret: 0000,
        scope: 'https://api.equifax.com/business/consumer-credit/v1',
    };

    try {
        const response = await axios.post(
            environment.equifax_api_url + 'v2/oauth/token',
            querystring.stringify(token_params)
        );
        console.log('--response--', response.data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
    console.log('--before after--');
}
```

I got access token from POSTMAN authentication popup.
[image]

Comment: When you make that request in Postman, it is most likely sending along an "Authorization" header which I don't see in your axios request. I can see Postman is using basic auth which is just a username + password concatenated and then base64 encoded so you will need to do the same and add it as a header on the request. I suggest using the "auth" option in axios: https://masteringjs.io/tutorials/axios/basic_auth

Comment: @nerdybeast it's not related with authorization params, I have already unchecked authorization headers params in postman.

Answer (score 0):

Mistake was client_id and client_secret not usedful in token_params so just add
btoa function is not available on nestJS you have to install btoa https://www.npmjs.com/package/btoa and then include client_id and client_secret in headers params.

```
const client_id = 0000;
const client_secret = 0000;

const token_headers = {
  Authorization:
    'Basic ' +
    btoa(
      client_id +
        ':' +
        client_secret
    ),
};


async getEquifaxToken() {
const token_params = {
    grant_type: 'client_credentials',
    client_id: client_id,
    client_secret: client_secret,
    scope: 'https://api.equifax.com/business/consumer-credit/v1',
};

try {
    const response = await axios.post(
        environment.equifax_api_url + 'v2/oauth/token',
        querystring.stringify(token_params),
        {headers:token_headers}
    );
    console.log('--response--', response.data);
    //Here I got token successfully.
} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
}
```

}